# Implications of using PersonAccounts and stopping Contacts sync?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Are there any pitfalls of carrying over and syncing 0 contacts from the CRM and relying on PersonAccounts entirely? Mainly because Contacts increase contact counts in Contact Builder, PersonAccounts don't (until you send to them), and there seems to be no limit in utilizing PersonAccounts and using PersonContactId in Journey's, regular email sends etc.

What's the catch here, did they overlook this "loophole" in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct synced person accounts are not automatically added into contact count. Only the contacts gets added into count.
But any which ways if you try to send them or use it in journey by adding data extension into the data designer will add into SFMC contact count.